# Python extract search results from monster.com

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've seen the results for google extracting but it doesnt work for this. I would like to simply go into the code and change the parameters and when ran, it does the search and scrapes the job titles, locations, and date. This is what I have so far. Any help would be great and thanks in advance.

I would the script to execute a search on monster.com with the given params (engineer software CA) and scrape the results.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import re
import requests
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

parameters = ["Software","Engineer","CA"]
base_url = "http://careers.boozallen.com/search?q="
search_string = "+".join(parameters)

final_url = base_url + search_string

a = requests.get(final_url)
raw_string = a.text.strip()


soup = BeautifulSoup( raw_string )

job_urls = soup.findAll(name = 'a', attrs = { 'class': 'jobTitle fnt11_js' })

for job_url in job_urls:

    print job_url.text
    print

raw_input("Press enter to close: ")
```

I know this, below, works as a standard scrape.

```
handle = urlopen("http://jobsearch.monster.com/search/Engineer_5?q=Software&where=AZ&rad=20&sort=rv.di.dt")
responce = handle.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup( responce )

job_urls = soup.findAll(name = 'a', attrs = { 'class': 'jobTitle fnt11_js' })
for job_url in job_urls:
    print job_url.text
    print
```

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? If you have a specific question about something not working you can ask that but we can't fix your program for you.

Comment: I would the script to execute a search on monster.com with the given params (engineer software CA) and scrape the results.

Comment: @Garrett - that's a request for us to do your work, which we don't do.  What we do here is fix problems with existing code.  Show us what you've done, how it does and doesn't work and then wait for hints and fixes.

Comment: maybe you need to put "&" instead of "+" in your search_string at the top?

Comment: i did the code i posted, and from my limited python knowledge i thought it would work. it didnt, so im asking for help where i went wrong, and its not work just a time killing project that i want to do.

Comment: tried it, still returns no results. thanks though. and why is this being marked down? im simply asking for help with my project. I thought it would work and need help

Comment: @Garrett Looking at the HTML, the `<a>` tag you're trying to filter doesn't have the `attrs = { 'class': 'jobTitle fnt11_js' }` parameters. You might need to filter first by the table (which has #searchResults ID) and then for the `<a>` tags inside.

Comment: I have the original scraper that works after ive gone to the site, searched and copied the url in the script. It works for that but maybe not for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you point your browser at `http://careers.boozallen.com/search?q=software+engineer+CA` and inspect the HTML you'll see HTML like this:

```
<tr class="dbOutputRow2">
    <td style="width: 400px;" class="colTitle" headers="hdrTitle"><span class="jobTitle"><a href="http://careers.boozallen.com/job/San-Diego-Network-Engineer%2C-Senior-Job-CA-92101/1645793/">Network Engineer, Senior Job</a></span></td>
    <td style="width: auto;" class="colLocation" headers="hdrLocation"><span class="jobLocation">San Diego, CA, US</span></td>
    <td style="width: 155px;" class="colDate" headers="hdrDate" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="jobDate">Jan 5, 2012</span></td>
```

The information you are looking for are in `<span>` tags, with `class` attributes equal to `jobTitle`, `jobLocation`, or `jobDate`.

Here is how you could scrape these bits using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as LH

url = 'http://careers.boozallen.com/search?q=software+engineer+CA'
doc = LH.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))

def text_content(iterable):
    for elt in iterable:
        yield elt.text_content()

data = text_content(doc.xpath('''//span[@class = "jobTitle"
                                        or @class = "jobLocation"
                                        or @class = "jobDate"]'''))

for title, location, date in zip(*[data]*3):
    print(title,location,date)
```

yields

```
('Title', 'Location', 'Date')
('Network Engineer, Senior Job', 'San Diego, CA, US', 'Jan 5, 2012')
('Network Integration Engineer, Mid Job', 'San Diego, CA, US', 'Jan 12, 2012')
('Systems Engineer, Senior Job', 'San Diego, CA, US', 'Jan 31, 2012')
('Enterprise Architect, Senior Job', 'Washington, DC, US', 'Jan 23, 2012')
...
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but is there anyway to change something around to work with import xml.etree.ElementTree as et. In my current environment i cant use lxml. Thanks.